# Query returning 0 rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I'm building very simple search engine for a job site. It has 3 optional input fields, term, category and employer. Term and employer fields are text input and category is dropdown list. 
Search logic is very stupid, complicated and not scalable but this search is meant to be used just one time and all i need from it is that it works on a few cases and since i have more important things to do at the time i didn't tried to make it any better.

This is the method that returns a DataSet with results of a search.

```
private DataSet GetResults(string term, string category, string employer)
{
        string query = "SELECT * FROM Jobs ";

        MySqlConnection conn = DBConnection.Connect();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(term) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(category) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(employer))
        {
            cmd.CommandText = query;
        }
        else
        {
            query += "WHERE ";
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(term))
            {
                query += "Title LIKE '%@term%' OR Job_Desc LIKE '%@term%' ";

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(category))
                    query += "AND Category = @category ";
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(employer))
                    query += "AND Title LIKE '%@employer%' AND Job_Desc LIKE '%@employer%' ";
            }
            else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(category))
            {
                query += "Category = @category ";

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(term))
                    query += "AND Title LIKE '%@term%' OR Job_Desc LIKE '%@term%' ";
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(poduzece))
                    query += "AND Title LIKE '%@employer%' OR Job_Desc LIKE '%@employer%' ";
            }
            else if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(employer))
            {
                query += "Naziv LIKE '%@employer%' OR Job_Desc LIKE '%@poduzece%' ";

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(term))
                    query += "AND Title LIKE '%@term%' OR Job_Desc LIKE '%@term%' ";
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(category))
                    query += "AND Category = '@category' ";
            }
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@term", term.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", category.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employer", employer.Trim());
        }

        MySqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet searchResult = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(searchResult);
        conn.Close();
        return searchResult;
    }
```

The problem is the folowing. When i search only for a term or employer i get 0 rows in return but i get results for category which is selected from dropdown list and is not queried with LIKE condition but with =. My guess at first was that i got something wrong with LIKE operators and with OR and AND but when i manualy query the database with the same query that is built in code, i get results. 
My next guess is that i got something wrong with paramaters because if i replace parameter placeholders with actual user query i get results.

This works.
    query += "Title LIKE '%C programmer%' OR Job_Desc LIKE '%C programmer%' ";

Thanks for help and sorry for bad english. :)

Comment: are you looking something like "Title LIKE '%"+term+%' OR Job_Desc LIKE '%"+term+"%'' ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the parameters value used in the LIKE operator with % and not in the query

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@term", "%" + term.Trim() + "%");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", category.Trim());             
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@employer",  "%" + employer.Trim() + "%");
```

of course remove the % in the query text. Also there is no need of the single quote in front of every string parameter as you already do for the @category parameter

However this code requires further refinements. If you don't have a term value or employer value, the formed sql string doesn't contains the placeholder for the respective parameter. However, at the end, all the parameters are added. Thus, the command will fail with unexpected parameter exception.